# Integral in solution of geodesic problem

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

In the textbook Classical Dynamics by Greenwood, in solution for geodesic problem, we come across an integral

> $$\int\frac{cd\theta}{sin\theta\sqrt{sin^2\theta-c^2}}$$

where the author takes the liberty to jump straight to the answer:

> $$\phi=\cos^{-1} \frac{c \cot\theta}{\sqrt{1-c^2}}+\phi_0$$

I vaguely remember doing substitutions twice to reach the answer last time I solved it, but  have completely forgotten how I did it. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$\int\frac{c\ d\theta}{\sin\theta\sqrt{\sin^2\theta-c^2}}=\int\dfrac{c}{\sin^2\theta \sqrt{(1-c^2)\left(1-\frac{c^2}{1-c^2}\cot^2\theta\right)}}\ d\theta$$
now let substitution
$$\cos\phi=\frac{c}{\sqrt{1-c^2}}\cot\theta$$

Comment: Thank you! Figured it out!

Comment: You are welcome dear :)